# golang: текст в struct поле типа int

Tags: golang

Что обозначает запись такого вида, а точнее для чего указывать текст в типе `int` и как получить этот текст?

```
type User struct {
    Age int `gorm:"size:255"`
}

fmt.Println(User{}) // {0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это **метка**, в ней можно держать **метаданные** для поля. В данном конкретном случае это [метка для `gorm` (ORM такая) о типе данных этого поля в БД](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/models.html#model-definition).

Из себя они представляют разделённый **пробелами** набор пар `ключ:"значение"`, окружённый обратными кавычками (`` `метаданные` ``), вроде JSON'ового объекта, только проще: только строковые ключи и строковые значения. Пример побольше:

```
`foo:"bar" baz:"quux"`
```

Доступ к таким меткам производится через рефлексию, [вот пример](https://play.golang.org/p/Al_m3GYl5j) ([отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30889373/2076787)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type User struct {
        Name  string `mytag:"MyName"`
        Email string `mytag:"MyEmail"`
    }

    u := User{"Bob", "bob@mycompany.com"}
    t := reflect.TypeOf(u)

    for _, fieldName := range []string{"Name", "Email"} {
        field, found := t.FieldByName(fieldName)
        if !found {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("\nField: User.%s\n", fieldName)
        fmt.Printf("\tWhole tag value : %q\n", field.Tag)
        fmt.Printf("\tValue of 'mytag': %q\n", field.Tag.Get("mytag"))
    }
}
```

---

```
Field: User.Name
    Whole tag value : "mytag:\"MyName\""
    Value of 'mytag': "MyName"

Field: User.Email
    Whole tag value : "mytag:\"MyEmail\""
    Value of 'mytag': "MyEmail"
```